# XML-RPC: best way to handle 64-bit values?

Tags: c++, python, 64-bit, xml-rpc

So the official XML-RPC standard doesn't support 64-bit values.  But in these modern times, 64-bit values are increasingly common.

How do you handle these?  What XML-RPC extensions are the most common?  What language bindings are there?  I'm especially interested in Python and C++, but all information is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some libraries support 64 bits extensions, indeed, but there doesn't seem to be a standard. [xmlrpc-c](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/), for example, has a so called i8 but it doesn't work with python (at least not by default).

I would recommend to either:

- Convert the integer to string by hand and send it as such. XMLRPC will convert it to string anyway, so I would say this is reasonable.
- Break it in two 32 bits integers and send it as such.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "i8" as a data-type is becoming more and more common. I recently added this to my Perl XML-RPC module (http://metacpan.org/pod/RPC::XML) in response to a request from a large group that needed it in order to work with a server written in Java. I don't know what toolkit the server used, but it was already accepting i8 as a type.

One thing that I feel still has to be addressed, is whether the "int" alias for "i4" should also accept i8, the way it currently does i4. Or, for that matter, if a parameter typed as i8 should quietly accept an input typed as i4. XML-RPC has great potential as a lightweight, low-overhead protocol handy when you don't need all the coverage of SOAP, but it is often overlooked in the religious wars between REST and SOAP.

XML-RPC is in need of some updating and revision, if we could just get the original author to permit it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about how XMLRPC could be extended but I did find [this mail](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-May/381032.html) about the subject:

> In XML-RPC, everything is transmitted
>   as a string, so I don't think that
>   choice is really that bad - except of
>   course for the additional clumsiness
>   for invoking explicit conversion
>   functions.
>
> But no, XML-RPC doesn't have a data
>   type that can represent integers above
>   2**32. If you can accept losing
>   precision, you can use doubles (but
>   you still would have to convert
>   explicitly on the sender).

Answer (score 0):

[XML-RPC.NET](http://www.xml-rpc.net/) has supported <i8> since release 2.5.0 (5th September 2010).